# How to dynamically SET search_path for SECURITY DEFINER functions outside of function definition?

Tags: security, postgresql

I understand that it is essential to SET search_path for all SECURITY DEFINER functions.  However, I am writing code for a project where the primary schema could be either the 'public' schema, or some other schema (let's call it 'foo').  This causes problems as hardcoding the 'public' schema into the search path will break portability.  Instead, I have considered using ALTER ROLE to SET the search_path or all users that will have access to the function.  That way, deployments using the different schema names will only have to worry about changing the search path for the roles.

My question is, is it a security risk to *not* SET search_path within the function definition, but within all roles with permission to perform the function?  Or does this not behave as I would expect?  Is there a better way to dynamically SET search_path for SECURITY DEFINER functions outside the function definition?

Comment: You can use the extension infrastructure for this. Package your code as an extension and use its support for schema relocation.

Comment: "*is it a security risk to not SET search_path within the function definition, but within all roles with permission to perform the function?*" - yes. Any user can overwrite the search_path for their current session.